# python-social-auth custom redirect url in Django

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am using `python-social-auth` package along with Django to manage oauth and openID logins.

Now the issue is that, I can specify one redirect url in django `settings.py`, but in some case I want the user to be redirected to the same page from which he initiated the authentication process.

E.g:  if my redirect url is : `/home/` and I am currently in a page `/products/product1` from which I authenticate the user, then I want the user to be redirected to `/products/product1/` rather than `/home/`

Please help me solve this problem or at least some materials that covers this in detail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

I'm pulling your answer out of the question and placing it here for future reference.

Adding a parameter  `?next={{request.get_full_path}}` to the `auth` url.

Answer (score 6):

A bit better is to conditianally add next when it exsists

```
 <a href="{% url 'social:begin' "google-oauth2" %}
    {% if request.GET.next %}?next={{request.GET.next}}{% endif %}">
      <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/login-google.png" alt="Google">
 </a>
```